Adjust header size in a flextable in R for a pdf output
I am struggling with a wide table that have to be outputed in PDF from R-Markdown.
I tried different solutions to have it in one page, the best option looked to switch to landscape mode (fine for me), reduce font_size (also ok) rotate header line (also ok), and adjust the size of this same header line. This is the issue, it does not look it works once in pdf. I have read this issue to understand that height and hrule are not working for pdf. But then, does someone have a solution?
output as is
Here is my simplified code.
---
title: "Layout issues are the worst"
author: "team X"
date: "2024"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

\blandscape

table2 %>% 
  regulartable() %>% 
  fontsize(size = 11) %>% 
  fontsize(size = 9, part = "header") %>% 
  rotate(rotation = "btlr", part = "header", align = "center") %>%
  width(j = NULL, width = 0.8, unit = "cm") %>%
  width(j = "`Cellule/Secteur`", width = 2, unit = "cm") 

\elandscape



Are you able to output as html_document? then you can print that to a PDF.
